# How to trigger a java.net.NoRouteToHostException

Tags: java, testing, networking

I work on a test suite for a HTTP client. During the development one of the errors we encountered was `java.net.NoRouteToHostException`. I read that this error is encountered when the machine is unable to find a proper next hop (e.g., non-existent host on local network). However, I am unable to reproduce this error in our test suite.

I already tried:

- using non-existent DNS name (got `cannot resolve host` instead)
- using non-existent IP on restricted network that I'm not connected to (e.g. 10.1.1.1 when I'm only in 192.168.1.0/24) - got `request timeout` instead
- using unused IP on the network I'm connected to (e.g. 192.168.1.154 when I'm in 192.168.1.0/24 and I know for sure that there is no 192.168.1.154 machine) - I tried both LAN and WiFi, got `request timeout` instead

So, my question is: how to set up an environment to run the test suite so that I'd be able to trigger `java.net.NoRouteToHostException`? I'd prefer a Java-only solution, but I can live with Docker if it's necessary.